# Unbind all objects of a rule transact sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sap-ase

How can i unbind all the objects associated to a rule in transact sql before i can drop the rule?

In case that i can´t unbind in one step how can i see to which objects the rule is binded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to see which objects are bounded to the rule , after that to unbind the rule from a table you simply do this:

sp_unbindrule table, null, "all"